# Opening sms thread goes into incorrect thread

Tags: htc-desire, sms

When using my mobile (HTC Desire), I would say I use sms more often than actually using it as a phone.

Because of this, I have a fairly huge history of sms threads (I really like how HTC Desire displays the sms conversation). However, I've realised that every so often when I hit on say sms thread with "person A" I actually get sms thread with "person B". At first I thought it was just me accidentally hitting the one below. However, today this happened three times (tried to open personA, but got personB instead) and the thing is there is a gap of ~8 between person A and personB... so impossible for me to accidentally hit the wrong one...(plus the repeated occurrence is quite annoying!)

Was wondering if anyone has a similar experience or know why this is happening... also preferably how to fix it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug, and it's not entirely clear if it's the SMS application or Android's SMS implementation itself. You can see the ticket [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12592), which was closed on Jan 29, 2011. The fix has been slow getting out to phones other than the Nexus line because carriers haven't released updates that include it.

One option in the meantime would be to try an alternative SMS app, such as [Handcent](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms) or [ChompSMS](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.p1.chompsms&feature=search_result). However, though many people say that it does help, others have reported that the bug still persists on 3rd party apps.

There is also a [reportedly related bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9392) that causes outgoing messages to be sent to the wrong recipient. The "opening the wrong thread" bug was closed as a duplicate of the "wrong recipient" bug, as the fix for the latter apparently applied to the former (according to Google).

Comment: Great answer, thanks for pulling together all this information.

Comment: Reading about the "wrong recipient" bug makes me more worried... wouldn't like messages being 'randomly' sent to an unintended recipient :O Guess i'll just have to wait for the update/fix. Thanks for the info :)