# Why do get SMS send to the wrong recipient ( HTC Thunderbolt)?

Tags: sms, htc-thunderbolt

My SMS texts on numerous occasions have crossed from one thread of text and gone to a completely different person.  That person usually has recently texted me.  I close out the keyboard and make sure it is going to the right person, hit send, then **it ends up going to the wrong thread.**

Is there a fix for ?

Comment: Sounds like you might be experiencing [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9392), which has actually come up on this site previously (related question [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/9073/981)).

Answer (score 3):

There are many people facing similar problem here, http://community.htc.com/na/htc-forums/android/f/107/t/12961.aspx?PageIndex=3

The solutions they came up with was:

1. Use [handcent](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms&hl=en) SMS app instead of stock SMS app
2. Keep low number of messages in inbox
3. Delete read message
4. Waiting for Gingerbread update which will fix it

If I were you I'd choose number 1.

Comment: See also [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9392) on the Android tracker.